# PATH-variable in wsl 2 gets always reset . How to fix that?

Tags: go, ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

after I reset Ubuntu (wsl2) from apps I can't set, for example,

> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin

I mean it set, but after I closed the terminal all config got reset and I should

> export PATH=$PATH: /usr/local/go/bin

Again, even I remove wls and ubuntu completely and reinstall, but nothing change

Comment: Just a friendly, neighborhood reminder that questions on this site should be about *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Your question appears to be about *general Linux usage and configuration* (albeit under WSL) and would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com), or the [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackexchange.com). That said, this question almost certainly already has multiple related questions and answers on those sites, so please search first before reposting.

Answer (score 17):

First, this is the expected behavior of most shells. In your bash shell, the exported variables are only kept for a session. You need to add the `export` command to your `~/.bashrc` file. The file is sourced every time you open the shell.

You can run `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin' >> ~/.bashrc` to add the command to the bashrc file, or use your editor of choice. After adding the export command, run either `source ~/.bashrc` or restart your shell.

Go should be available after this.

This also works if you have a python module installation path that needs to be added to the source.